# SQL - Trying to correlate data

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm just learning SQL. The data set I have looks like this:

```
city_name |  work_place_name | min_commute_time | max_commute_time
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Austin        CONGRESS           25                 45
Austin        NASA               10                 12
Austin        CIRCUS             16                 35
CEDAR PARK    CONGRESS           35                 65
CEDAR PARK    NASA               28                 60
CEDAR PARK    CIRCUS             26                 55
KYLE          CONGRESS           50                 85
KYLE          NASA               60                 100
KYLE          CIRCUS             60                 100
```

I'm trying to figure out which city will have a min commute time of less than or equal to 30 for both CONGRESS and NASA. I came up with the following query, but I'm not getting the results that I am looking for.

```
SELECT city_name
FROM commute_times
WHERE min_commute_time<=30 AND (work_place_name='NASA' OR work_place_name='CONGRESS')
```

The results that I am getting are:

```
city_name 
-----------
Austin
Austin
Cedar Park
```

The results that I am hoping for are:

```
City_name
-----------
Austin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close.  Aggregation will fill in the missing piece:

```
SELECT city_name
FROM commute_times
WHERE min_commute_time <= 30 AND 
      work_place_name IN ('NASA', 'CONGRESS')
GROUP BY city_name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Comment: Thank you, Gordon!!